# Intersection graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

Does anybody know of a paper which proves that finding the maximum independent set in geometric intersection graphs is NP hard? Even general intersection graphs?

Comment: You might want a list of NP-hard cases? I think the hardness depends on the dimension, the shape and geometric restriction, and in some case it's not NP-hard.

Answer (score 5):

According to graphclasses.org it is NP-Hard in

grid intersection: http://graphclasses.org/classes/gc_739.html

rectangle intersection:  http://graphclasses.org/classes/gc_1179.html

Click in "Details" for reference or other graph class.

The query for intersection is:

http://graphclasses.org/classes.cgi?search=intersection